Trying to understand Liouville's theorem
I am reading about Liouville's theorem on Wikipedia, and I think I understand what it is trying to say, but thinking in some examples I get into troubles.
What I understand so far, is that a non-piecewise power series cannot become a constant in a non-zero measure interval (don't matter if its real or complex valued), since it would violate the Identity theorem (correct me please if I am wrong, I also learned this from Wikipedia - I am self studying math).
I some similar fashion, Liouville's theorem "states that every bounded entire function must be constant". I understand that Entire functions are specific kind of complex-valued power series, and in their Wikipedia site is stated: "Typical examples of entire functions are polynomials and the exponential function, and any finite sums, products and compositions of these, such as the trigonometric functions, (...) and their hyperbolic counterparts (...), as well as derivatives and integrals of entire functions such as the error function. (...)  On the other hand, the natural logarithm, the reciprocal function, and the square root are all not entire functions (...)".
So I think to myself, "lets check with the Taylor series of a bounded function to see what happens", so I choose $f(x) = e^{-x^4}$ which is a exponential function that fulfill the following characteristics:

$f(x)$ is continuous and class $C^\infty$, so well behaved
$f(x)$ is bounded since $f(x)\geq 0$ always, and $f(x)\leq \|f(x)\|_{\infty} = 1$
$f(x)$ only vanishes at infinity

Now is when I get into troubles, since I am very rusty in complex analysis: I am not sure if $f(x)$ is an entire function, but I think it is since Wikipedia definition, I Google it and found mixed answers like in here or here, but if I try their Taylor series it is just:
$$T_f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^kx^{4k}}{k!}$$
So if $f(x)$ is analytic (which I think it is), then $T_f(x)$ should be as bounded as $f(x)$, and obviously $T_f(x)$ is not a constant since matches $T_f(x)\,\overset{k\to\infty}{\Rightarrow}\, f(x)$, so obviously I have misunderstood something in Liouville's theorem.
Hope you could explain why the $f(x)$ example don't match the theorem.

this is about complex functions on the plane and for $z=ir, r >0$ one has $e^{-z^2}=e^{r^2}$ is obviously unbounded; the theorem is not true on the real line ($\sin x$ is an even simpler example) or for real analytic functions only (see $1/(1+x^2)$ which is real analytic on the whole real line and bounded)

$f$ is not bounded as a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Look at the values of $f$ on the ray ${ re^{i\pi/4}}$

@Conrad Thanks I understand know, is not something like if $z=x+iy$ fulfill then also does $z|_{y=0}$. The Identity Theorem on the other side applies to real-valued and complex-valued power series, right?

the identity theorem does apply to both yes

An entire function, or an integral function, is a complex-valued function that is holomorphic (complex differentiable in a neighbourhood of each point in a domain) on the whole complex plane.

@Conrad Could I ask you to place your comments as an answer in order to close the question?

no problem - added a few more considerations on the topic

@Joako May I ask why it seems you are using Wikipedia as your primary source for learning complex analysis?  It is better as a reference than as a way to learn math -- even the site agrees.  You might be better served by picking up a good book on complex analysis.

@user806050 I am not specifically trying to learn complex analysis, but instead to make myself a better overall idea of how functions in general behave, I have met in this search some very interesting theorems in Wiki but as you said sometimes is too abstract and lack examples. My scope is to understand systems of finite duration and why they have been some how avoided in classic literature, but mainly focus in real-valued signals.

Note that the Liouville Theorem is about entire functions which means  complex analytic functions in the plane. For $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ we have $f(ir)=e^{r^2}$ which is clearly unbounded when $r \to \infty$ real.
The Theorem doesn't hold if restricted to the real line as noted above or using $\sin x$ as another counterexample (or any other line, or even all lines at the same time as there are nontrivial analytic functions bounded on ANY line in the plane though they take a bit of work to construct).
Also the theorem doesn't hold for analytic functions on the real line that do not necessarily extend as entire functions as $1/(1+x^2)$ shows.
As an aside most domains in the plane (except the full plane or domains with boundary consisting only of isolated points) do admit non constant bounded analytic functions
